# Yii Ajax Submit-Button

Tags: php, yii

I have this ajax button in my _table view.

This _table view is rendered partially through AJAX form submission in my main view.

The problem is when I click submit (the button in the _table view) the submitted data are the ones
being serialized in my main view or in other word the ajax button in my main view takes the action
instead of the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you haven't used renderPartial's "processOutput" param, so your inside JS isn't working. And main view has such ajax button, so "_table" ajax button have processed with main view JS...
So try:

```
$this->renderPartial("_table", array(), false, true);
```